# How to extract network diagnostic logs on iPhone without Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, logging, cfnetwork

I'm looking for an easy way how to figure out which requests are blocked by Application Transport Security on device.

According to [CFNetwork Diagnostic Logging](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1887/_index.html) I can do it by enabling `CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS` environment variable and thats perfectly works for simulator - I can see log file by path that provided in console and log file is not empty.

But I have faced an issue that I cannot extract this logs just by fetching them in `NSLibraryDirectory` on iPhone. Logs are created on iPhone, but they are empty.

Is there any way to access this log file on device or extract information in this log programatically?

**Update:** It seems like extracting .xcappdata with cfnetwork logs via Xcode download container is not working also. All cfnetwork logs are zero bytes size.

Comment: Did you find any solution?